# Background color doesn't entire apply to button

Tags: css

I'm trying to apply background color to submit button

Here is button styleClass:

```
.buttonMarginClass{
    background: aqua;
    width:100%;
    height: 40px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I'm excepted that background will be apply to entire area of the button. But really I have:

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: Are you referring to the border? Set `border: 0;` and see if that's what you're expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do the trick:

```
border: 0;
outline: 0;
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the border color as well

```
border-color:aqua;
```